# Call to action with image on your youtube video automatically through API?

Tags: youtube-api

I try to dynamically change / add an overlay CTA on my videos through API of youtube. Is it possible? or is there any workaround?

Comment: Show us your code with what you tried.

Comment: I didn't find any api to do so